# CSS (click) animation wont play several times in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, animation

I've tried it in Chrome and Safari and the animation runs every time when I press the Open link, but in Firefox the animation only runs the first time I press the link. After that, when I press the link it doesn't load the animation. Is there anything I can do to make the animation run every time I press the link?

Here's what I'm working with:

http://jsfiddle.net/p5hkyovs/4/

```
<div id="over">
    <div class="animation">Fade in - <a href="#start">Back</a></div>
</div>
<div id="start">
<a href="#over">Open</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#over {
    display: none;
}
#over:target {
    display: inline-block
}
#over:target ~ #start {
    display: none;
}
div.animation {
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation:fadeIn .5s ease-in-out;
    animation:fadeIn .5s ease-in-out;
}
.fadeIn {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the missing mozilla vendor prefix for the `animation-name: fadeIn;` value.

Try this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p5hkyovs/5/)